# No route between Nameko and Flask

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, nameko

if you saw my last question one hour ago or almost) !

I managed to resolve a lot of problems but I'm stuck with one and I can't understand why I have it. I prefer to make a new thread because the error isn't the same and for future readers, it will be clearer.

My goal, as I said in the last question, is to have microservices with Python and Nameko, sending results and receiving informations and queries from a Flask webapp (and in the future, from many Flask web app). But I now have a - 312 - route problem.

Code from my Nameko app :

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*

# namekotesting.py

from nameko.rpc import rpc

class firstService:
        name = "First microservice"
        result = "";

        @rpc
        def mymethode(self, test):
                result = test
                return result
```

Code from Flask app :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, request
from flasgger import Swagger
from nameko.standalone.rpc import ClusterRpcProxy

app = Flask(__name__)
Swagger(app)
CONFIG = {'AMQP_URI': "amqp://guest:guest@<myipserverhere>:5672"}

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def mymethode():
        with ClusterRpcProxy(CONFIG) as rpc:
                littletest = rpc.firstService.mymethode("hello")

def index():
        return littletest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5000)
```

And now, the error :

```
 * Serving Flask app "flasktest" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 126-185-375
[03/Jun/2018 21:04:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/oyo/flasktest/flasktest.py", line 16, in mamethode
    petittest = rpc.premierService.mamethode("voici")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/rpc.py", line 368, in __call__
    reply = self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/rpc.py", line 437, in _call
    extra_headers=extra_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/amqp/publish.py", line 189, in publish
    **publish_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 494, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 203, in _publish
    mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1743, in basic_publish_confirm
    self.wait(spec.Basic.Ack)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 79, in wait
    self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 491, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 497, in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 77, in on_frame
    callback(channel, msg.frame_method, msg.frame_args, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 501, in on_inbound_method
    method_sig, payload, content,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 128, in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1960, in _on_basic_return
    raise exc
ChannelError: Basic.return: (312) NO_ROUTE
```

I'll stay on this thread now to finish my tests (if I have another problem I can't solve). After that, I think I will be able to make my framework thanks to that. Any advice, hints or help for this one, for the moment ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute on the service class is how you address the service.

```
class firstService:
    name = "first"

    @rpc
    def method(self):
        pass
```

So

```
>>> rpc.firstService.method()  # won't work
>>> rpc.first.method()         # will work
```

Also it looks like you're using a too-modern version of py-amqp. Did you upgrade it since installing Nameko? It should be v1.4.9. With that version you get a more helpful "Unknown Service" error returned.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't remember having upgraded it (as I look on my history, I don't see any command for that since the first install with apt-get install, that's strange). I tried your code without any result. Should I try to downgrade it ? I didn't do it once but I could try. Or I could remove them all and reinstall it ?

Comment: Just to say : I installed greenlet, kombu, python-dev and python-yaml after installing Nameko. I needed it. Could it be the problem ? Nameko couldn't run without it (some errors apparead).

Comment: I uninstalled them all then re-installed it and it worked. It just worked with rpc.firstmicroservice.mymethod() with firstmicroservice as the name. That's all I needed. Thank you all for your help !

Comment: Nameko's setup.py specifies that it requires a kombu version < 4.x, which in turn requires amqp < 2.x. If you `pip install nameko` it will install appropriate dependencies for you. If you subsequently `pip install kombu` without specifying a version you'll get the latest one, even if it clashes with something else in your environment. That's part of [how pip currently works](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988#issuecomment-360846457).

You can use [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) to view the dependency tree of an environment including any clashes.

Comment: Actually, as of pip 10 you'll get a warning when installing any library that clashes. e.g. `nameko 2.9.0 has requirement kombu<4,>=3.0.1, but you'll have kombu 4.2.1 which is incompatible.` The installation still proceeds though.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ sends back with 'basic.return' when a 'mandatory' message cannot be delivered to any queue.

Can you run this ?

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

and then open

```
http://server-name:15672/ #server-name i think is `localhost`
```

logged in with acc `guest` and password `guest` [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

and there will be all information about `queues` `channels` `exchanges` etc.

is there the `queue` declared where you want to send the message ?

if there is not `queue` create it

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already done the first one, even created a new user. But I can't reach the proper URL, the connection failed (I replaced server-name by the server IP). I'm going to look for it, I don't know why it failed.

Comment: `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service ` rabbitmq is active?

Comment: I changed my comment (again). It was active but I managed to go to the management page thanks to that : github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/364. I have two queues : `rpc-First microservice D idle 0 0 0 rpc.reply-standalone_rpc_proxy-1c1b5ea9-e2a5-45c0-a494-15223d4d6bbd Exp D idle 0 0 0` The error is still here.

Comment: Ah, shouldn't I see "running" instead of "idle" here ?

Comment: you have `First microservice` queue, in the future don't use space between words in queue you can name it `first_microservice` and now, do you send message to this queue ? and do you received message from this queue ?

Comment: Thank you again. I first thought it was just a name and wrote it. But even with firstmicroservice, it's always "NO_ROUTE". I just see that I have a rpc-firstmicroservice (idle / D) and another one with random numbers and letters after "rpc.", it seems, with EXP / D parameters and in idle mode. That's all for my queues.